# How to Use the NSIS Unzip Plugin properly?

Tags: nsis, unzip

Im new to NSIS programming, so i found the NSISUNZ plugin to extract files.

This is my Code:

```
OutFile "TEst.exe"
Section
!addplugindir nsisunz
initPluginsDir
nsisunz::Unzip "C:\Users\user\Downloads\TestVerzeichnis.zip" "C:\Users\user\Downloads"
SectionEnd
```

I do not get an Error or something but the file does not get extracted.
For the installation of the plugin I just extracted the .dll file into the plugins folder.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for answering

Comment: Are you building a Ansi or Unicode installer?

Comment: You are not using `Pop $0` to get the result!

Comment: Added Pop $0 now. It just says "E" + "completed" in the output console

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong installing the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output is just a single letter then you most likely using the Unicode version of the plug-in in a Ansi installer.

Ideally you should create a Unicode installer with NSIS v3:

1. Move the plug-in to the Unicode plug-in subfolder inside the root plugins folder.
2. Add `Unicode True` to your .NSI.

If you are still using NSIS v2 then you need to find a different version of the plug-in, most likely the other file on the wiki.

```
Unicode True
!addplugindir /x86-unicode "$%userprofile%\Downloads\Nsisunz\Plugin unicode"

!include LogicLib.nsh
Function SplitWrite
Pop $2
StrCpy $3 ""
StrCpy $4 0
loop:
    StrCpy $5 $2 1 $4
    ${If} $5 == "|"
    ${OrIf} $5 == ""
        IntOp $6 $4 - 2
        StrCpy $6 $2 2 $6
        FileWriteByte $1 "0x$6"
    ${EndIf}
    IntOp $4 $4 + 1
    StrCmp $5 "" 0 loop
FunctionEnd

Section
InitPluginsDir
; Create a example .zip file 
FileOpen $1 "$PluginsDir\test.zip" w
Push 50|4B|03|04|0A|00|00|00|00|00|AC|BA|93|50
Call SplitWrite
Push F8|06|53|6B|08|00|00|00|08|00|00|00|08|00|00|00|54|65|73|74|2E|74|78|74|48|65|6C|6C|6F|20|0D|0A|50|4B|01|02|3F|00|0A|00|00|00|00|00|AC|BA|93|50
Call SplitWrite
Push F8|06|53|6B|08|00|00|00|08|00|00|00|08|00|24|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|20|20|00|00|00|00|00|00|54|65|73|74|2E|74|78|74|0A|00|20|00|00|00|00|00|01|00|18|00
Call SplitWrite
Push D6|75|96|79|90|16|D6|01|96|4F|96|79|90|16|D6|01|96|4F|96|79|90|16|D6|01|50|4B|05|06|00|00|00|00|01|00|01|00|5A|00|00|00|2E|00|00|00|00|00
Call SplitWrite
FileClose $1

CreateDirectory "$PluginsDir\TestDir"
nsisunz::Unzip "$PluginsDir\test.zip" "$PluginsDir\TestDir"
Pop $0
DetailPrint $0 ; "success"
${If} $0 == "success"
    FileOpen $1 "$PluginsDir\TestDir\Test.txt" r
    FileRead $1 $2
    FileClose $1
    DetailPrint $2 ; "Hello"
${EndIf}

SectionEnd
```

Comment: Okay thanks after adding the "Unicode True", it does at least say: "Error opening Zip File". I am using v3 of NSIS

Comment: Could be a problem with the .Zip or perhaps the path is incorrect?

Comment: Double checked the path and the file, both should be fine. So I dont know what is wrong with my code

Comment: Works fine for me, I'll add a example.